# Batch processing of a large JSON file with jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have a large JSON file which is an array of many objects which I want to submit to an API that accepts bulk data uploads. I've learned that I can use jq's stream mode to avoid loading the entire file into memory:

```
jq --stream -nc 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' < data.json | curl ...
```

I'd like to batch this so I'm making a request in batches for, say, 100 objects at a time.

Comment: Don't forget the -n command-line option!!!

Comment: I saw that advice but I wasn't clear on why. "Don’t read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once using null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch." It seems to work without it, and I don't want to use jq as a simple calculator, either. If it's important, why isn't it implied by --stream?

Comment: Yes, it's potentially a bit confusing, but if you omit the -n then you'll lose one JSON entity.  Compare `echo 1 | jq -n --stream inputs` and the same thing without the `-n` option.

Answer (score 2):

You could use GNU parallel:

```
< data.json jq --stream -nc '
    fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' |
  parallel --pipe -N100 curl ...
```

Or more generically:

```
< data.json jq --stream -nc '
    fromstream( inputs|(.[0] |= .[1:]) | select(. != [[]]) )' |
  parallel --pipe -N100 curl ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this using the `mapfile` built-in from Bash 4:

```
while mapfile -n 100 LINES && ((${#LINES[@]})); do
    echo "Uploading ${#LINES[@]} records..."
    echo "${LINES[@]}" | curl --silent ... --data-binary @- >/dev/null
done < <(jq --stream -cn 'fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))' < data.json)
```

Comment: WARNING: without the `-n` option, this invocation of jq will in effect skip the first JSON entity in data.json

Answer (score 1):

If your input is an array, then the paths will all start with a number (the index into the array). You could effectively paginate that array by filtering by the indices.

```
$ jq --stream -n --argjson skip 0 --argjson top 100 '
[fromstream(1|truncate_stream(
    inputs | . as [[$index]] | select($index >= $skip and $index < $skip + $top)
))]
' data.json | curl ...
```

Just set the skip argument to the appropriate offset.

I set up an example in the playground so you can play around with it. [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/ykntRWS17I)